# spyOn a Subscription.unsubscribe() - testing angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test

I'm trying to test if a subscription unsubscribe method is called and I'm getting an error.

My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import {
 Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'; import { LoaderService } from
 '@core/components/loaders/services/loader.service';

 @Component({   selector: 'loader-mask',   templateUrl:
 './loader-mask.component.html',   styleUrls:
 ['./loader-mask.component.css'] })

 export class LoaderMaskComponent implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;

   ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    } 
    }
```

and my test looks like this

```
it('should call unsubscribe() on ngOnDestroy', ()
=> {

 let spy = spyOn(component['subscription'], 'unsubscribe').and.callFake( () => {});
    component.ngOnDestroy();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();   });
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for unsubscribe()
```

Comment: component calls `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`, you test `component['wizardSubscription'].unsubscribe` ...

Comment: Also the unsubscribe should not be called from the unsubscribe callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const spy = spyOn(
  (component as any).subscription,
  'unsubscribe'
).and.callThrough()
component.ngOnDestroy();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Try this, I had the same problem and as far as i remember i used above way to solve it. Please check and verify.

Comment: this did not work for me. "cannot spy on primative" but @Anudeep answer worked for how to create the subscription

Answer (score 4):

```
component.subscription = new Subscription();
const subscription = spyOn(component.subscription, 'unsubscribe');

component.ngOnDestroy();

expect(subscription).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```